# Errors building QT 5.5.1 source code on Win32

Tags: qt, static, mingw

I'm trying building new version 5.5.1 on win32 
After

```
configure -static -release -opensource -qt-sql-sqlite –platform win32-g++ -opengl desktop
```

and

```
MinGW-make
```

after just one minute:

```
c:\mingw\include\math.h: In function 'float hypotf(float, float)':
c:\mingw\include\math.h:635:30: error: '_hypot' was not declared in this scope
 { return (float)(_hypot (x, y)); }
                              ^
Makefile.Release:316: recipe for target '.obj/release/moc.o' failed
mingw32-make[4]: *** [.obj/release/moc.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'c:/Qt/5.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1
/qtbase/src/tools/moc'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'c:/Qt/5.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1
/qtbase/src/tools/moc'
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'sub-moc-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-moc-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'c:/Qt/5.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1
/qtbase/src'
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/Qt/5.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1
/qtbase'
Makefile:68: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I read that maybe possibly perform construction msvc or try mingw64 but I need it on Windows 32 with platform win32-g++
You really can not build this version with win32 and win32-g++ platform??
Any suggestions please, welcome any help.

***SOLUTION.................................................................................................................................................***

You can compile QT 5.5.1 with MinGW-64 project.
This project also works on 32 bits.

It´s not possible to compile with the "typical" version minimalist, neither changing the libraries. MinGW-64 project is not available from MinGW Installation Manager, I do not understand this and dislike me as an advocate for alternatives like mingw, I could always download from this manager all I need, now this manager... should improve.

After installing MinGW-64 project in all programs MinGW-64 project Run terminal

```
cd pathQTconfigure
configure -static -release -opensource –platform win32-g++ -opengl desktop
mingw-make
```

THANKS TO ALL :)

Comment: You chopped the actual error off your paste above. What are the lines before `Makefile.Release:316: recipe for target '.obj/release/moc.o' failed`?

Comment: @andlabs sorry I edited

Comment: I remember having this problem. AFAIK it's a mingw bug. Fix the header (math.h) and it should compile. Or try newer mingw if possible.

Comment: (by newer mingw you want mingw-w64 specifically)

Comment: You might want to try MinGW 4.9.2, which is used by the “official” Qt 5.5.1/mingw packages. (according to the docs, 4.8.x should work though)

Comment: @andlabs Right, I've tried MinGW-64 and it works. THANKS TO ALL.